# Make jQuery function update on the fly

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code:

```
function viewport() {
var height = $(window).height();
viewport = parseInt(height) + 'px';
$(".page").css('height',viewport);
$(".dot_page").css('height',viewport);
}
```

All it does is resize a div according to the viewport height. This happens once during the page load, but I would like it to update dynamically if the viewport is resized without reloading the page (someone just resizing their browser with their mouse).

Thank you

Comment: You should be using css: `height: 100%`

Comment: @zzzzBov CSS never works properly with 100% height, even if the Body and HTML are also 100% height. Having a pixel value for the height is the only guaranteed way to have the height be 100% of the viewport, whether it be on a desktop or phone.

Comment: "CSS never works properly with 100% height..." - [that's a very bold, and very false claim](http://jsfiddle.net/6U4Tn/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [resize](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) event on the window object

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  viewport();
});
```

You should also change your function because:

```
viewport = parseInt(height) + 'px';
```

reassigns the viewport variable, which is initially the function to

```
var heightString = parseInt(height) + 'px';
```

with both of these, it should fix your problems.

The `resize` event assignment should be in a `$(document).ready` call.

With all your code, this looks like:

```
<script>
function viewport() {
  var height = $(window).height();
  var viewportHeight = parseInt(height) + 'px';
  $(".page").css('height',viewportHeight);
  $(".dot_page").css('height',viewportHeight);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  viewport();
  $(window).bind('resize', viewport);

  $(".scroll").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 1250);
  });

  $(".circle_col > a > img").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, 200);
    },
  function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, 200);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: When trying this I get this error in Firebug:

ReferenceError: viewport is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

viewport();

I tried moving my original code into a document ready but it didn't work.

Comment: Here is a fiddle of what's in my script tag. It's the only JS on the page. http://jsfiddle.net/mCE6J/ I'm not sure if something is conflicting.

Comment: I tried all of the suggestions you edited in but I'm new to jQuery and I broke it every time. Would you mind editing this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/mCE6J/

I really appreciate it!